# how to get Dagger2 Compiler Options working?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2, dagger

I'm trying to use 3 of the dagger2 compiler options in my android project.
but it seems none of them actually work.

I have pasted the code from [here](https://google.github.io/dagger/compiler-options.html) to my gradle.properties and even compiler options of AS settings.

the 3 that I'm interested in are:

```
-Adagger.fastInit=enabled
-Adagger.formatGeneratedSource=disabled
-Adagger.gradle.incremental
```

the fastinit and codeformatting just don't work (judging by the code that is generated) but the incremental cause a compile error saying:

```
no compiler option found.
```

the versions that I'm using are:

dagger : 2.18

gradle : 5.2.1

kotlin : 1.3.21

androidPlugin : 3.3.1

Answer (score 5):

For projects with multiple modules, the top build.gradle can be updated with this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        extensions.findByName('kapt')?.arguments {
            arg( "dagger.formatGeneratedSource", "disabled" )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should try without "A"

```
dagger.fastInit=enabled
dagger.formatGeneratedSource=disabled
dagger.gradle.incremental=enabled
```

Also can try directly in build.gradle, but this should be done for each project.

```
kapt {
    arguments {
        arg('dagger.fastInit', 'enabled')
        arg('dagger.formatGeneratedSource', 'disabled')
        arg('dagger.gradle.incremental', 'enabled')
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try without A. almost the same results

Comment: we have almost 50 modules in our project, as you mentioned I can not use the gradle script in every build.gradle